# Passing pointer to a function and print its value when the function ends

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPrueba(char * prueba){
    prueba = malloc(sizeof("dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf"));
    sprintf(prueba, "dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf");
}

int main(){
    char * prueba;
    printPrueba(prueba);
    printf(prueba);

    free(prueba);
}
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPrueba(char * prueba){
    prueba = malloc(sizeof("dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf"));
    sprintf(prueba, "dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf");
    printf(prueba);
}

int main(){
    char * prueba;
    printPrueba(prueba);

    free(prueba);
}
```

Why is the second code working fine and the first not?
How can I write the code to "force" it work like the first way?

Comment: You don't allocate enought space, as the string is NUL terminated you need one byte more

Comment: You know you can accept an answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the pointer by value.
What it means?
It means that the functions copies the address that the original one is pointing, and then you allocate memory inside the function, but the original function has no idea about this new address.

Imagine the following:
Your original pointer (p1) holds the address 0x2444
Then you pass it by value to the function. What the function does is copy the 0x2444 to a new pointer (p2), then it allocates memory and change the address to 0x5555.
Now p2 points to 0x5555, but p1 still points to 0x2444, So whatever you put on p2 doesn't affect p1, p1 still points to the original location 0x2444.

That's why it's not printing what you expect after the function is finished.

To work the way you expect you can pass the pointer by reference 
char**

Or you can return the new pointer from the function to the caller.

This simple change make your code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPrueba(char ** prueba){
    *prueba = malloc(sizeof("dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf"));
    sprintf(*prueba, "dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf");
}

int main(){
    char * prueba;
    printPrueba(&prueba);
    printf(prueba);

    free(prueba);
}
```

And to test the original code to see how both pointers are pointing to a different location you can do this change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPrueba(char* prueba){
    printf("P2 BEFORE ALLOC: %p\n", prueba);
    prueba = malloc(sizeof("dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf"));
    sprintf(prueba, "dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf");
    printf("P2 AFTER ALLOC: %p\n", prueba);
}

int main(){
    char * prueba;
    printPrueba(prueba);

    printf("P1: %p\n", prueba);
    printf(prueba);

    free(prueba);
}
```

You can see that both P1 and P2 before alloc points to the same address, but after the allocation they point to completely different addresses.

Memory allocation can be a bit tricky, but hope that those examples help you to understand :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (Thanks every body for the answers in fact), seems like I am not good at all with pointers X_X.

Comment: @Atoj The first thing you need to have in mind is that a pointer is nothing but a variable that store an address (and this address can contain a value, garbage, another address, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For first code to work refer the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printPrueba(char **prueba){
    *prueba = malloc(sizeof("dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf"));
    sprintf(*prueba, "dlkafñlasdjfñlasjdfñlasjdfñlasjdfñljasdlñfjaslñdfjsñladjfñlsadjf");
}

int main(){
    char * prueba;
    printPrueba(&prueba);
    printf(prueba);

    free(prueba);
}
```

Here I am passing the address of the char pointer to the function. So that if in the function I change the value of the pointer it should also change in the caller function.

In your case the arguments to the function is passed using pass by
value, which now would be pass by reference